# Dual boot Ubuntu Windows Asus Zen Book

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I've tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my Asus Zen Book 14 - model UX434F - in dual boot with Windows 10 without success...
I've disabled both fast boot and secure boot. Then, I've launched Ubuntu installation using a flash USB and I've selected to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. Unfortunately, the installation fails when Grub is installed.

```
Unable to install Grub. This is a fatal error.
```

How can I fix this problem? I have any idea to solve this. I would appreciate any suggestion, thank-you in advance.

Comment: Are you installing in UEFI boot mode? Have you updated UEFI and if SSD, updated SSD firmware?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Shows Windows screens
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi